# Test error after react-router migration to version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I moved to react-router-dom v6 from v5 and some tests are failing with the error below.
My guess is that there is some route mismatch so that nothing is actually rendered.

```
RouterProvider(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. 
Or, to render nothing, return null.

      41 |              },
      42 |      )
    > 43 |      return render(
         |                      ^
      44 |              <RouterProvider
      45 |                      router={memRouter}
      46 |                      fallbackElement={<p>Test DOM is loading</p>}
```

Here is my custom render method:

```
type TestRenderProps = Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'> & {
    initialState?: Partial<RootState>
    store?: any
    dispatch?: any
    route?: string
    history?: string[]
}

export function customRender(
    ui: React.ReactNode,
    {
        initialState,
        store = getTestStore(initialState || {}),
        dispatch,
        route = '/',
        history = ['/'],
        ...renderOptions
    }: TestRenderProps = {},
) {
    const memRouter = createMemoryRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
            <Route path={route} element={ui} errorElement={<TestErrorBoundary />} />,
        ),
        {
            initialEntries: [...history],
        },
    )
    return render( // ---> from react testing library
        <RouterProvider
            router={memRouter}
            fallbackElement={<p>Test DOM is loading</p>}
        />,
        {
            ...renderOptions,
            wrapper: props => (
                <StoreProvider {...props} store={store} dispatch={dispatch} />
            ),
        },
    )
}

const StoreProvider = ({
    children,
    store,
    dispatch,
}: {
    children?: React.ReactNode
    store: any
    dispatch: any
}): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <Provider store={dispatch ? { ...store, dispatch } : store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Here is how the custom render is used in one of failing tests

```
test('test!', () => {
    customRender(
        <p>test</p>,
        {
            initialState,
        },
    )

    expect(screen.queryByText(/app.update/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.queryByText(/app.close/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.queryByText(/doctor.signPrescription/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

From code above, route should be just '/' and it should match.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `MyComponent` returning valid JSX? Can you [edit] and include `MyComponent` as part of the [mcve]?

Comment: I replaced `MyComponent` with some simple and valid JSX and the issue is present nonetheless. I believe it is not even rendered and that the issue is in the `customRender`, but I cannot understand what is wrong

Comment: What's `RouterProvider`?

Comment: @LinDu here it is https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider